# placeholder works for text but not password box in IE/Firefox using this javascript

Tags: javascript

Js File

```
//Modified from http://www.beyondstandards.com/archives/input-placeholders/
function activatePlaceholders()
{
    var detect = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
    if (detect.indexOf("safari") > 0) return false;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
    {
        if (inputs[i].getAttribute("type") == "text")
        {
            var placeholder = inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder");
            if (placeholder.length > 0)
            {
                inputs[i].value = placeholder;
                inputs[i].onclick = function()
                {
                    if (this.value == this.getAttribute("placeholder"))
                    {
                        this.value = "";
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                inputs[i].onblur = function()
                {
                    if (this.value.length < 1)
                    {
                        this.value = this.getAttribute("placeholder");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (inputs[i].getAttribute("type") == "password")
        {
            var placeholder = inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder");
            if (placeholder.length > 0)
            {
                inputs[i].value = placeholder;
                inputs[i].onclick = function()
                {
                    if (this.value == this.getAttribute("placeholder"))
                    {
                        this.value = "";
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                inputs[i].onblur = function()
                {
                    if (this.value.length < 1)
                    {
                        this.value = this.getAttribute("placeholder");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
window.onload = function()
{
    activatePlaceholders();
}
```

Html part

```
<form name="input" action="login.php" method="post">
        <table width="*" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />&nbsp;<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" /><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">Stay logged in:&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign Up | Forgot Password&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

This works for the input box. Not working for the password box. It wants to star out the place holder text on the password. I want to users password to be started out but not the place holder. Not sure how to fix that so it works in IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var passwords = document.getElementsByTagName("password");
```

Should be:

```
var passwords = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

As it's `<input type="password">` not `<password...>`. However, I don't think that will help you in this case, because when you set the value of the password, all you'll see are the black dots/asterisks.

Comment: Thanks... Now i ran in to another problem. It wants to star out the word password on the placeholder.... I want it to star out the users password but not the place holder word "password". Trying to use place holders so i don't cuter up the UI.