# cakephp - Password field have plain-text default placeholder but invisible when user types

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I have a password field:

```
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('default'=>'Password', 'class'=>'formInput', 'id'=>'password'));
```

But because this is a password field, the default placeholder value of 'Password' appears as lots of *'s (lots of stars)

Is there a way to make the password field allow plain text until the user types into it?

Comment: Have you tried? `echo $this->Form->input('password', array('default'=>'', 'class'=>'formInput', 'id'=>'password', 'placeholder' => 'Password'));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML: HTML5 Placeholder attribute in password field issue- shows normal text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523888/html-html5-placeholder-attribute-in-password-field-issue-shows-normal-text)

Comment: hi guys, thanks. the placeholder thing was awesome

Comment: Scrap that thanks. NOTE this solution using placeholder will not work on all browsers. Thanks for mentioning that cryptic cheers